# Not sure how to insert mock data into database

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to insert records into a database. I can't figure out the correct way to insert the following JSON data into the database.

```
data2={
"id": 2,
"name": "The Dueling Pianos Bar",
"genres": ["Classical", "R&B", "Hip-Hop"],
"address": "335 Delancey Street",
"city": "New York",
"state": "NY",
"phone": "914-003-1132",
"website": "https://www.theduelingpianos.com",
"facebook_link": "https://www.facebook.com/theduelingpianos",
"seeking_talent": False,
"image_link": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497032205916-ac775f0649ae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80",
"past_shows": [],
"upcoming_shows": [],
"past_shows_count": 0,
"upcoming_shows_count": 0 }
```

So far I have tried to do the following -

```
INSERT INTO venues (id, name, genres, address, city, state, phone, website, facebook_link, seeking_talent, image_link) VALUES (2, 'The Dueling Pianos Bar', '['Classical', 'R&B', 'Hip-Hop']', '335 Delancey Street', 'New York', 'NY', '914-003-1132', 'https://www.facebook.com/theduelingpianos', False, 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497032205916-ac775f0649ae?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80');
```

I don't think this is the correct way to do it; it's returning the following error-
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Classical"
LINE 1: ...age_link) VALUES (2, 'The Dueling Pianos Bar', '['Classical'...

Any ideas as to how these records could be inserted into the database?

Comment: `'['Classical', 'R&B', 'Hip-Hop']'` because this isn't quoted correctly.

Comment: that's exactly what i wrote :/

Comment: Yes, and it isn't correct because your single quotes around the whole `[...]` interfere with tthe single quotes inside of it! You can use bound parameters for your queries or use double quotes for the quotes _inside_ of the string and single quotes around the field data like: `'["classical", "R&B", "Hip-Hop"]'`. Using bound parameters means you can easily re-use the code for all _mock data_ (although this may depend on exactly what database you're using)